# Do I need to javadoc every single method or just the 'main' method in java?

Tags: java, javadoc

Java example method:

```
//Stores the user input into an integer variable called 'choice'
int choice = keyboard.nextInt();
```

Do I need to write javadoc for a simple method like this or should I only document the main method of any program, if so then what sort of things should I write for the main method?

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 10):

This was explained in your other thread:
[What should I write in my javadoc class and method comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834621/need-some-help-with-javadoc/1834645#1834645)

What you have posted is not a method either.  You do not need to comment every line of code, even for an assignment.  If you have something obvious such as:

```
i++;
```

You do not need to comment it with "increments i by one."

Again, code comments (including JavaDoc) do not affect the execution of the code.

Answer (score 4):

Need?  That depends on what you mean by "need".

I think there's a few confusions in your question.   One of them is what constitutes a method.  You seem to be asking about comments in general.  Javadocs are a specific form of comment (with a particular syntax).  Also, a quibble: your example above isn't a method.  It's a single line of code.

But addressing just that, I wouldn't use that comment.   *Clearly* you're setting a variable called "choice".  The only thing interesting there is what nextInt does, but anyone curious should be able to hover over the nextInt() method and see its javadocs.

Answer (score 2):

First off, that example is not javadoc, just a code comment

Here is a tutorial on javadoc
[How to write javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/writingdoccomments/)

And you should only javadoc public facing methods